# Applying nth-chlid(even) on table not working on dynamic table generated through jsp but works with static table

Tags: css, jsp, jstl

I am applying css to change the color of alternate rows using nth-child(even).
It is working file if the rows are static,but if I generate table dynamically using jsp then css not applied. How it can be resolved ?

css is :

```
table tr:nth-child(odd)
  {
    background-color: #94B8B8;
  }
table tr:nth-child(even)
  {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
  }
```

and jsp is:

```
    <c:forEach var="item" items="${items}" varStatus="i" begin="0" step="1">
 <tr>
<td>some data</td>
<td>some data</td>
 </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

generated html look like:

```
            <tr onclick="selectRow(this)" id="1" >
                <td>
                    item1


            </td>
                <td>i1 </td>

            </tr>



            <tr onclick="selectRow(this)" id="2" >
                <td>
                    Item2


            </td>
                <td> 2 </td>

            </tr>
```

Comment: what does your generated html look like.

Comment: see the edited code i mentioned the generated html

Answer (score 0):

**Used to this way**

`Even` or `odd` for your `table` and now define `.tableBg` `class` define your table

```
.tableBg tr:nth-child(odd)      { background-color:#eee; }
.tableBg tr:nth-child(even)     { background-color:#fff; }
```

Answer (score 0):

How are you adding the generated code to your existing document? I had this problem while directly editing a table's html. The code that produced the problem looked like this:

```
var table = document.getElementById('myTable');
table.innerHTML = "<tr>             \
                     <td>xx</td>    \
                     ...            \
                   </tr>";
```

To fix the problem, I created a tbody element, edited its html, and appended that element to the table. That code looked like:

```
var table = document.getElementById('myTable');
var tbody = document.createElement('tbody');
tbody.innerHTML = "<tr>             \
                     <td>xx</td>    \
                     ...            \
                   </tr>";
table.appendChild(tbody);
```

Hopefully, this will help with your problem.